# how to play track from certain position using spotify apps API

Tags: spotify

I am developing spotify third party application using javascript API.
I am trying to play the track from certain position.
I am having following code,

**player.position = 50000;
player.play(track);**

But this code plays track from begining.
I want to play the track from certain position.
Is there any way to play track from certain position?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also link directly to a specific position in a track by adding `#1:31` to the end of a URI, for example `spotify:track:3iDK8BAaBUatPR84gdfa9g#0:15`.

Answer (score 4):

You need to play the track first, then as soon as playback starts seek to the location you want.

You can observe when playback starts by adding an observer for `models.EVENT.CHANGE` to the player object and looking at the `playing` property.

Comment: I am beginner in spotify app develpement. I had tried using position property of Player, Unfortunately I am not able to play the track from specific position(track plays from begining). Can you tell me how to add observer for models event. I will be very thankful if you will able to give sample code for adding observer for models event to set specific position of currently playing track. Thanks